# ajaxSubmit calls the success callback even when there is an error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using jquery.form.js and ajax to submit my forms. The problem I have is even when it's not on success (when there is an error) also the ajax is resetting the form no matter it is in code only to do it on after success.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#FileUploader').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
        //show uploading message
        $("#loadding").html('<div class="loader"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please Wait"/> <br/><span>Submiting...</span></div>');
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#output',
            success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
        });
    });
});

function afterSuccess()
{
    $('#FileUploader').resetForm();  // reset form
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
    $('#loadding').html('');
}
</script>
```

Can someone point out where is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you tell there is error? You don't seem to handle any error event.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#output',
            success:  afterSuccess,
            error:error
        });

function error(response,status,xhr){
alert("error");}
```

will work as i had implemented same concept in my project and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the http status code of the server response if an error occuring ? 

For jQuery, `success` = 2xx http status code return in the response and `error` = 4xx

If you didn't change the header of response, for your jQuery code, it's always a success!!!

So 2 solutions :

1. You can change the http header code status if it's an error.
2. You can return a different content in response and check it in your `success` function.

Other point: change the definition of the success property like behind.

```
success:  function () { afterSuccess(); } //call function after success
```

Why ? Because, if you declare directly the function, it will be execute during the ajaxSubmit() configuration, maybe it's solve your problem, because before the response of the server, `afterSuccess()` will be called.

Comment: success:  function () { afterSuccess(); } //call function after success solved my issue.

Answer (score -2):

The `success` event will always fire if the HTTP response code is in the 200-299 range (or === 304), anything else and it won't fire. So I'm guessing that your server side code responds with `200 OK` even when there is a problem.

If the server outputs a value such as `true` you can test the response text for that:

```
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#output',
        success:  function(response) {
            if(response == "true") {
                afterSuccess();
            }
        }
    });
```